# difference between two time interval ios components swift 3

Tags: ios, date, swift3, nstimeinterval

I have two time interval basically i want to convert find out difference between them this is my code. but, its not works

```
 func dateformatter(date:Double) -> String {

    let timeElapsed:TimeInterval = TimeInterval(Int(date))
    let timeNow:TimeInterval = TimeInterval(integerLiteral: Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000))

    let date2:Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeElapsed )
    let date1:Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeNow )

    let calender:Calendar = Calendar.current
    let components:DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date1, to: date2)
    var returnString:String = ""
    print(components.second)
    if components.second! < 60 {
        returnString = "Just Now"
    }else if components.minute! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.minute) + " min ago"
    }else if components.hour! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.hour) + " hour ago"
    }else if components.day! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.day) + " days ago"
    }else if components.month! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.month)+" month ago"
    }else if components.year! >= 1 {
        returnString = String(describing: components.year)+" year ago"
    }
    return returnString
}
```

Comment: when components calls it returns nil

Comment: where is `timeElapsed ` and `timeNow` parameters coming from?

Comment: @dirtydanee i update it see

Comment: can you also specify what does that mean `it is not works`? What error are you receiving?

Comment: components.second  returns nil

Comment: You need to include `.second` component when initializing the `DateComponents` instance: `let components: DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date1, to: date2)`. That aside, read up on optionals and _safe ways of unwrapping these_ (`... myOptional!` is not safe!).

Comment: its solve but still one problem occurs 
when assign date2 then they have  value but date1 assign then date2 value is nil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for all the conversion you doing at the beginning of the function. `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` accepts `NSTimeInterval`, however, it is only a `typealias` for `double`.

Also, because your first `if` statement check for `seconds` you need to include `.seconds` to the component parameter list.

Your could do the following:

```
func dateformatter(date: Double) -> String {

    let date1:Date = Date() // Same you did before with timeNow variable
    let date2: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)

    let calender:Calendar = Calendar.current
    let components: DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date1, to: date2)
    print(components)
    var returnString:String = ""
    print(components.second)
    if components.second! < 60 {
        returnString = "Just Now"
    }else if components.minute! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.minute) + " min ago"
    }else if components.hour! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.hour) + " hour ago"
    }else if components.day! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.day) + " days ago"
    }else if components.month! >= 1{
        returnString = String(describing: components.month)+" month ago"
    }else if components.year! >= 1 {
        returnString = String(describing: components.year)+" year ago"
    }
    return returnString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, there is an error in your logic which makes the function return "Just now" in every case. So here is the modified code:

```
func timeElapsed(date: Date) -> String {

        let date1:Date = date
        let date2: Date = Date() // Same you did before with timeNow variable

        let calender:Calendar = Calendar.current
        let components: DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date1, to: date2)
        print(components)
        var returnString:String = ""

        print(components.second!)

        if components.second! < 60 {
            returnString = "Just Now"
        }

        if components.minute! > 1{
            returnString = String(describing: components.minute!) + " mins ago"
        }
        else if components.minute! == 1 {

            returnString = "A minute ago"
        }

        if components.hour! > 1{
            returnString = String(describing: components.hour!) + " hours ago"
        }
        else if components.hour == 1 {

            returnString = "An hour ago"
        }

        if components.day! > 1{
            returnString = String(describing: components.day!) + " days ago"
        }
        else if components.day! == 1 {

            returnString = "Yesterday"
        }

        if components.month! > 1{
            returnString = String(describing: components.month!)+" months ago"
        }
        else if components.month! == 1 {

            returnString = "A month ago"
        }

        if components.year! > 1 {
            returnString = String(describing: components.year!)+" years ago"
        }
        else if components.year! == 1 {

            returnString = "A year ago"
        }

        return returnString
    }
```